# List of elements into object

Tags: java, jackson, xml-parsing

I have some structure like

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "dataModel")
public class DataModel {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "group")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Group> group;
...

}

@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Group {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "element")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false, localName = "elements")
    private List<Element> elements;

   ....
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Element implements Cloneable {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "name")
    private String name;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "value")
    private String value;
}
```

And this works fine, but I want to change my List to new class Elements

```
class Elements {

        private List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

How I must change my annotation to do that work?

Addition. This is a part of my XML. Maybe you know something about OBIP, it was created by that. Oracle BI Publisher... It seems sound like that.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>

<dataModel xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/xmlp" version="2.0" xmlns:xdm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/xmlp" xmlns:xsd="http://wwww.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   
     <group name="G_1" label="G_1" source="control_subject_params">
          <element name="PARAM_NAME" value="PARAM_NAME" label="PARAM_NAME" dataType="xsd:string" breakOrder="" fieldOrder="1"/>
          <element name="PARAM_VAL" value="PARAM_VAL" label="PARAM_VAL" dataType="xsd:string" breakOrder="" fieldOrder="2"/>
    </group>

</dataModel>
```

Any ideas?
Actually I can change List to Groups

Comment: Could you attach the XML (or a relevant part of it) you're parsing?

Comment: @Jonasz It was from file, but I include a part of it

Answer (score 0):

I think creating such a wrapper cannot be handled out of the box by Jackson only based on annotations, so a custom `Deserializer` is required.

```java
private static final TypeReference<List<Element>> ELEMENT_LIST_TYPEREF =
        new TypeReference<>() {};

@Override
public Group deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
    // Elements class is fully managed by the deserializer here
    // that's why there are no annotations in places where it occurs in the code
    var elements = new Elements();
    var elementNodes = parser.readValueAsTree()
                             .get("element");
    try (var traverse = elementNodes.traverse(parser.getCodec())) {
        List<Element> elementsList = traverse.readValueAs(ELEMENT_LIST_TYPEREF);
        elements.setElements(elementsList);
    }
    var group = new Group();
    group.setElements(elements);
    return group;
}
```

Module with deserializer can be registered like so:

```java
var module = new SimpleModule("GroupDeseriaizerModule");
module.addDeserializer(Group.class, new GroupDeserializer());
xmlMapper.registerModule(module);
```

We're registering a deserializer for `Group` as `Elements` class is an artificial wrapper and it's not marked with Jackson annotations. If we did mark it, it could be harder to parse the elements and save it for the object (each `element` from the XML is a separate deserialized instance).

---

[Here you can find a repository](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/tree/73340254/spring-boot-module/src/main/java/io/github/jonarzz) where I've reproduced the problem and applied the deserializer code shown above. [The test](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/blob/73340254/spring-boot-module/src/test/java/io/github/jonarzz/XmlMapperTest.java#L27) passed before the changes and now it also passes (I had to add an additional extraction `.extracting(Group::getElements)` since a new wrapper's been added).

Comment: Thank you for that, but these efforts are not justified. It is simpler to use old variant. I know that way, which you showed, but I didn`t want to use it